# How to programmatically backup exchange account for gmail in android app

Tags: java, android, gmail, exchange-server

I'm writing app for backing up and restoring some android data and settings (for rooted device). I successfully managed to back up call and sms databases, home layout and rom (system) settings but now I need to understand if (and how) it is possible to back up exchange accounts in order to restore and reuse them in gmail app after new rom installation without manually setting. I was able to backup com.google.android.gm package data. Where are exchange accounts information stored in android?
It is possible to programmatically backup and restore them?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Titanium backup if the phone is rooted & enable app data backup before backing up all apps+data.

Comment: I use TB but I want to do it programmatically in java code. Just need to know where system stores exchange account settings to do it by my own